# ASP.net MVC6 show Empty in a form when for some datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am working on asp.net MVC6 .

I have a model

```
public class MeterValueViewModel: IAuditable
    {          
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate{ get; set; }
   }
```

I have this in my form

```
   <input asp-for="MyDate" class="form-control">
```

MyDate could be 1/1/1900 which is the default date in my application or any other valid date(any date greater than 1/1/1900 is considered valid in my system).

What I want to do is to **globally** set the date sothat my form show **empty** date when the value of **MyDate**  is 1/1/1900. It should do the same for another DateTime property in any ViewModel. So this should happen in any form.

Is there some sort of model binding or tag helper to take care of this globally?

Comment: My question is how to globally change it not one by one for every date Plus 1/1/1900 is not null so it will  still show b/se that comes from db to identify null dates in my app.

Comment: Unless something has changed in MVC 6 that I'm not aware of I think you need to look into writing a custom DateTime model binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit - Solution Using Tag Helpers

If you want to do this using tag helpers, create the following tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class DefaultDateTimeTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ValueAttribute = "value";
    private DateTime DefaultDateTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var value = output.Attributes[ValueAttribute].Value;
        if (value != null)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt)
                && dt.Date == DefaultDateTime)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute(ValueAttribute, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, register the helper in `~/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`.  I'm just registering all tag helpers in my local application, using the `*` syntax:

```
@using WebApplication1
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, WebApplication1
```

That's all there is to it.  Any `input` tag that has an `asp-for` attribute will be checked to see if it has a `value` attribute that contains a valid `DateTime`.  If it does, and the value equals `1/1/1900`, `value` will be set to an empty string.

#### Solution Using Editor Templates

You can solve this by using a shared editor template that will be used to render all types of `DateTime`.  To do that, you'll want to do the following:

1. Create a new `EditorTemplates` folder in your ~/Views/Shared folder.  The name is important, as it has special meaning in MVC, so name it the same as I've shown.
2. Create a new `DateTime.cshtml` view in this folder.  Again, the name is important as it will be matched against the type you wish to create a template for (in this case, a `DateTime` instance).

Once you've done that, it should look like this:

[image: DateTime editor template]

Open up `DateTime.cshtml` and change it to the following:

```
@model DateTime

@if (Model.Date == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
{
    @Html.TextBox("", "")
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", Model)
}
```

If the date being passed in matches your default date, it will render a textbox with an empty string, otherwise it will render your date as normal.

Comment: I am using mvc6. So check this stackoverflow.com/questions/31895914/… Is there a way do do this using TagHelpers.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed I've updated my answer to include a possible solution.

Comment: I am using your tag helper but I get the exception "Tag helpers must have a start and end tag or be self closing.] (40,77) Found a malformed 'input' tag helper. "

Comment: @AmeteBlessed This is because the tag you're using doesn't have an end tag, isn't self-closing, or is being minified by something else.  Your `input` tag should look like this: `<input value="something" />`.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed Try my edited version.  I've specified a `TagStructure` setting on the attribute, which might solve your problem.  It has 3 different settings, so if one doesn't work, try one of the others.

Comment: Thanks now the error is gone but the tag helper is not applying for those inputs as in my question which have asp-for attribute could something be contradicting?

Comment: @AmeteBlessed I've updated my answer again.  It works locally for me in the way you describe now.

Comment: Now it is working.I appreciate your taking time to make all those updates to make it right.

Comment: @AmeteBlessed No problem, I'm glad it's working for you. :)